# Self Updating Shell Script

Tags: shell

I am developing a gameserver shell script that has multiple smaller scripts for saving content, restarting, stopping, installing, updating, etc. Since this a script for the community, I need a way to allow me to work on it, and then push those changes to the users who use the script.

This is a basic concept of how I think it should work:

- User runs the script
- script downloads a version file off github
- script reads the version string from github and tries to match it with the version listed in the script itself
- if it doesn't match, download new script file (url never changes), replace and re-run the script

If this is something that seems possible (I assume it would), please inform me of the process.

Comment: That's a significant piece of logic, corner cases and debugging. Its more likely that there are tools that can do this for you. But, open-ended questions like this are not the focus for Stackoverflow and it will likely be closed as 'too broad'. Maybe `man git` will give you some ideas. Good luck.

Comment: You seem to have a reasonable description of the process — what more information do you need?  I'm not sure I'd recommend it, but it should work.  Just about.

Answer (score 0):

This was demoed at docker con 2015 yesterday.  But this might help.  https://github.com/docker/notary